# Debugging Web Application Visual Studio Redirect to My ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I have developed a web application in visual studio, when i attempt to debug my .aspx file and hit f5(debug) and i am being directed to the following page: [image]

I have never seen this before - what does this mean? I was expecting for it to open my web application in debug mode.

Seems to work if i manually put /LoginPage.aspx after the locahost

[image]

Comment: Could you please supply some more information? Nothing seems wrong, you're just starting your web application in debug mode, which shows a login page?

Comment: It means authentication is enabled and you need to log in.

Comment: this is not what i developed, i developed a login page which looks nothing of the sort. This seems to be some sort of default web site that is redirected when I run debug in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is just the default authentication login page that gets set up when you create a new ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio with authentication. If you have developed a login page yourself like you say, and don't want to use the default authentication, you should remove that default code, or, maybe easier, just start another project without authentication, and copy the existing code you wrote yourself.

Comment: I dont know how i set up a web application project with authentication or where the option is to do that? Where would i remove the default code for that?

Comment: But when i hit debug, it doesnt put the aspx file in automatically

Comment: When you create a new Web Application in Visual studio, in the second step, there is a button, 'Change Authentication'. You could set this to 'No Authentication'. However, using the default authentication seems to me a better idea then to setup your own login page. But I don't know your project offcourse or what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RA19: the link you provided is link to your own localhost. I can't access that from here. :-)

Comment: Check original question, added screenshot, and look at both URLs. When i hit f5, it automatically goes to localhost without the aspx name

Comment: I jsut created a new project and it automatically adds the aspx after local host but mine doesnt do that?

Comment: You probably want your default page changed to the 'LoginPage.aspx' page... The way you do this depends on the technology you are using, web forms, mvc, ... The default page is page that gets used when no page is specified after the 'localhost' url...

Comment: Recreated a new project and moved my files and seems to work now